# How to handle errors without execution halting

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a small dxl script and I need to return the number of assigned positions  from an array of, let's say, size 20 in which only 10 positions are assigned.

I tried to use noError() and lastError() functions, but after lastError() is called, the script is halted and I can't continue the execution.
Here's my code:

```
int returnArrayLength(string array[]){
    int lengthOfArray = 0,i = 0;
    for (i=0; i < sizeof array ; i++){
            noError()
            if (!null array[i]){
                lengthOfArray++
                print lengthOfArray         
            }
            if (!null lastError()){
                print "Exception caught!" // not printed
                break
            }   
    }
    return lengthOfArray
}

string labels[6]
labels[0] = "label0"
labels[1] = "label1"
labels[2] = "label2"
labels[3] = "label3"

print returnArrayLength(labels)  // not printed
```

The above code prints the following:
1 
2
3
4

How can I resume the execution after the lastError() function is called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was tougher than I thought it would be!

So, as it turns out, an unassigned element error halts the DXL program entirely. So what do we need to do?

Well, we need to run a snippet of code, in it's own environment, and let it crash if it needs to!

To do so, we need to create an eval_, pass it our array, and then have it return_ (which won't be executed if the eval_ fails)

Take a look:

```
int returnArrayLength(string array[]){
    int lengthOfArray = 0,i = 0;
    for (i=0; i < sizeof array ; i++){
        string scode = "noError()
            string ( &passedAr)[] = (addr_ "( ( addr_ array ) int ) ")
            string s = passedAr["i"]
            lastError()
            return_ \"Y\""
            if ( ( eval_ scode ) == "Y" ){
                lengthOfArray++
                print lengthOfArray         
            } else {
                print "Exception caught!" "\n"
                break
            }   
    }
    return lengthOfArray
}

string labels[6]
labels[0] = "label0"
labels[1] = "label1"
labels[2] = "label2"
labels[3] = "label3"

print returnArrayLength(labels)
```

What a fantastic little problem.

Resources I used to help solve this:

[How to pass an array into an eval_](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014440731&ps=25)

[eval_ , addr_ , and memory leaks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014942467)

[Testing for unassigned variables](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014458406) - This one doesn't quite work because of the nature of arrays, at least as far as I could tell!

In any case, thanks for the challenge!

Comment: that's a great solution!
yet another reason why I prefer not to use arrays at all if possible. Skip Lists ftw!

Comment: thanks for your "magic" solution Russell! I have also found a workaround that would have used much more memory than needed, but clearly your solution is better, so I'll stick with it ! :)